# How can I align my ImageView with my TextView in a LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, textview, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have the following ImageView and TextView:
[image]

Here is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/headerLinearLay" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/avatarImageView"></ImageView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/usernameTextView" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="4px"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

How can I make the image and the text be positioned at the same height? I also want the ImageView to be in the corner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Using alignBaseline for an image following text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102532/android-using-alignbaseline-for-an-image-following-text)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/headerLinearLay">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatarImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usernameTextView"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatarImageView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That sort of works, but the image is still not in the top corner, and the text overlaps the image a bit.

Comment: Sorry. I missed the "top corner" sentence. To fix it I've removed `android:layout_centerVertical`. The overlaping took  place becouse I put wrong id in `android:layout_toRightOf`. Now everything is fixed. Goog luck.

Comment: This not answer the question actually.Question is about Linear Layout.  "android:layout_toRightOf"  is not in Linear Layout.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple solution that works well. Essential here is to add: android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" to TextView

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usernameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_weight="0.04" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="204dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: Please describe your answer as well.